# How to select two-level data structure in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, typescript

I'm developing an online shopping application, which has two-level product type. Now I'm using MongoDB to store it. My programming language is TypeScript.

My model is like below:

```
class ProductTypeModel {
    _id: ObjectID;
    name: string;
    sort: number;   // sort
    status: number; // enable | disable
    children: Object[]; // sub types, like [{ _id: ObjectID('xx', name: 'xx', sort: xx, status: xx) }]
    create_time: Date;
    update_time: Date;
}
```

If we have data like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8fe56218de48345a6b7079"),
    "create_time" : ISODate("2018-09-05T14:17:06.912Z"),
    "update_time" : ISODate("2018-09-05T14:17:06.912Z"),
    "name" : "Books",
    "sort" : 0,
    "status" : 1,
    "children" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8fe56218de48345a6b7075"),
            "name" : "Computer",
            "sort" : 1,
            "status" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8fe56218de48345a6b7076"),
            "name" : "Math",
            "sort" : 2,
            "status" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8fe56218de48345a6b7077"),
            "name" : "Novel",
            "sort" : 3,
            "status" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I select types and children types with `status=1` ?

My current solution is to select base types first, and traverse to exclude children whose `status` is `0`. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: what is type in your scheme?

Comment: @matthPen Sorry, what type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$redact aggregation stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) this will do the job:

```
    db['03'].aggregate(
    [
        {
            $redact: {
                $cond: {
                      if: { $eq: [ "$status", 1 ] },
                      then: "$$DESCEND",
                      else: "$$PRUNE"
                    }
            }
        },
    ],
);
```

output :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8fe56218de48345a6b7079"), 
    "create_time" : ISODate("2018-09-05T16:17:06.912+0200"), 
    "update_time" : ISODate("2018-09-05T16:17:06.912+0200"), 
    "name" : "Books", 
    "sort" : NumberInt(0), 
    "status" : NumberInt(1), 
    "children" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8fe56218de48345a6b7075"), 
            "name" : "Computer", 
            "sort" : NumberInt(1), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8fe56218de48345a6b7077"), 
            "name" : "Novel", 
            "sort" : NumberInt(3), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1)
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How if I want to select with multiple `status`? I tried `if: { $in: [ "$status", [1, 2, 3] ] },` but no luck...

Comment: what version do you have? Just tried with $in condition, working for me. Beware, your 'root' status must match the condition too.

Comment: Mine throws exception: `exception: invalid operator '$in'`. I'm using MongoDB version 2.6.12. I searched a lot in Google and MongoDB official docs, didn't find an example of using `$in` in `$cond`. Can you please share your whole script to use `$in`?

Comment: ok. $in came with 3.4 version. But 2.6 is out of date, no more supported since oct, 2016! upgrade your version, or try with $or operator (if:{$or:[{$eq:["$status",1]},{$eq:["$status",2]}]}